# Whats wrong with this array sorting

Tags: php, html, arrays, sorting

Here is my code :

```
    <?php
    $a=array(10,8,6,5);
    $b=count($a);
    for($i=0;$i<($b-1);$i++)
    {
        for($j=1;$j<($b);$j++)
        {
            if($a[$j]<$a[$i])
            {
            $temp = $a[$j];
            $a[$j]=$a[$i];
            $a[$i]=$temp;
            }

        }

    }
```

I just want to know what's wrong in the above code ? because if i take 3 array values it works fine but for 4 its not working....can someone do the modification for the same code,and also please briefly explain why is it not working any issues with looping?I am not looking for different code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistakenly modified the bubble sort algorithm. Use standard one.

```
<?php
    $a=array(10,8,6,5);
    $b=count($a);
    for($i=0;$i<($b);$i++) //Changes over here
    {

        for($j=0;$j<($b);$j++) //Changes over here
        {
            if($a[$j]>$a[$i]) //Changes over here
            {
            $temp = $a[$j];
            $a[$j]=$a[$i];
            $a[$i]=$temp;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you manually sorting when you have [`sort`](http://php.net/sort)?

```
$a = array(10,8,6,5);
sort($a);
var_dump($a);
```

Similarly, why are you using temporary variables when you have [`list`](http://php.net/list)?

```
list($a[$i],$a[$j]) = array($a[$j],$a[$i]);
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply kolink,ya i know that there is  buidin function, but still iam looking for a program, as i have mentioned i dont need new code,i want to modify the above code itself ...bcos i want to know the exact logic :(

Answer (score 0):

try below code may be that will help.

```
<?php

function pr($array = array())
{
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";
}
    $a = array(10,8,6,5);
    $b = count($a);
    for($i=0;$i <= ($b-1);$i++)
    {
        for($j=0; $j < ($b);$j++)
        {
            if($a[$j] < $a[$i])
            {
                $temp = $a[$j];
                $a[$j]=$a[$i];
                $a[$i]=$temp;
            }
        }
    }
    pr($temp);

    pr($a);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a=array(8,6,5);
$b=count($a);
for($i=0;$i<($b);$i++)
{

    for($j=0;$j<($b);$j++)
    {
        if($a[$j]<$a[$i])
        {
        $temp = $a[$j];
        $a[$j]=$a[$i];
        $a[$i]=$temp;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: An answer should never only consist of code. Describe your changes and explain them.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop doesn't need to be executed n times (where n=number of elements to be sorted). Every time the outer loop executes, one more element at the end (for ascending order) is in the correct position. So, inner loop should not check those elements.

```
<?php 
$a=array(10,8,6,5);
$b=count($a);
for($i=0;$i<($b);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<($b-$i);$j++){ // this change will save time
        if($a[$j]>$a[$i]){
               $temp = $a[$j];
               $a[$j]=$a[$i];
               $a[$i]=$temp;
        }
    }

}
?>
```